# Is it possible to change playlist image using Spotipy?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am automating Spotify playlists by using Spotipy module and I want to edit the playlist's image. Is that possible?

Comment: The [documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.18.0/#spotipy.client.Spotify.playlist_upload_cover_image) has a method that will "Replace the image used to represent a specific playlist". Please try that and then ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: You should add a code as well. You don't have to just get answers. You should try it first yourself and then ask for any issue you get. That's how it works here man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can upload a playlist cover using Spotify API.

You can do it by sending a `PUT` request at `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}/images` this URL. Where you have to change `{playlist_id}` with your Spotify ID for playlist. Along with this link, you have pass the header, which must contain: Authorization, Content-Type and {playlist_id} variables. Where **Authorization** is the `access-token`, **Content-Type** must be `image/jpeg` and **{playlist_id}** is your unique spotify playlist id.
And the image you are uploading must be Base64 encoded JPEG image data, with maximum size of 256 KB.

If you still get stucked anywhere then please refer this official reference link of [spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#category-playlists)